# Configure the default Random Number Generator algorithm in Windows.

Tags: windows, random-number-generator

How do I configure the default random number generator on Windows? Windows 7 and above.

I would like to check whether the **"Dual Elliptic Curve Deterministic Random Bit Generator (Dual EC DRBG)"** algorithm is set or not. 
And if the default generator is set to "Dual EC DRBG", I would like to configure a more appropriate random number generator.

According to this [post on the Cryptography StackExchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10486/does-microsoft-use-dual-ec-drbg-by-default/16018#16018), configuring the random number generator is possible:

> **Windows has a mechanism for configuring the default RNG algorithm to be used by various parts of the system.** The default configurations for Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012R2, Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008R2 do not use Dual EC DRBG as the default random number generator algorithm. The default random number generator algorithm for these versions of Windows is AES_CTR_DRBG from SP800-90a.

Comment: there are dozens of (DP)RNGs implemented in windows for different purposes and are used by different pieces of system software. The thread you linked is not really a discussion of a specific protocol using a DPRNG, so you will have to first decide what aspect of windows you are wanting to check. you can find SecureChannel (TLS/SSL) settings in the registery as described here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/tls-registry-settings but that is only of so much use, so unless you run a webserver, its probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm mainly interested in the RNG used by BCRYPT: `BCRYPT_USE_SYSTEM_PREFERRED_RNG` (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptgenrandom ). So, there has to be a system preferred flag, no? OpenSSL also relies on the same rng to generate random numbers ([rand_win.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/rand/rand_win.c#L70)).

Comment: Since its OpenSSL and DPRNG (implying a stream cipher) I'm guessing you are looking at SecureChannel settings. I don't actually believe that the quote you copied from the other thread is correct (that there is a means to globally set encryption settings for all purposes). My experience has been with hardening IIS for TLS, and those are definitely settings specific to TLS.

Comment: No, I am really interested in secure random number generation. I used OpenSSL as an example to show how random numbers are typically generated - and how "best practices" look like. I am interested in this topic because we are looking into securely provisioning hardware devices on the factory floor.